# asp.net core 2 html helper for nullabe dates

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following code in my model

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? StartDateTime { get; set; }
```

and rendering it using

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="StartDateTime"></label>
    <input asp-for="StartDateTime" class="form-control" >
    <span asp-validation-for="StartDateTime" class="text-danger"></span>

</div>
```

It produced an input with mm/dd/yyyy in it initially.
I want the initial value to be blank hence why i set it as a DateTime? but I would like it to be required, forcing the user to enter a value.

Comment: What is the initial value in the input? Is it mere  mm/dd/yyyy or any date in that format??

Comment: thats what it puts in there, mm/dd/yyyyy

Comment: Selected date doesn't not show in input field??

Comment: @TanvirArjel there is no selected date, its suppose to be empty

Comment: if you are using DateTime as datatype the helper generate type="datetime-local" as type in html which is rendered and this will cause HTML 5 datepicker to display , it good to change datatype to string and use jquery datepicker.

Comment: Understood!!  Are you using jquery date picker??